# Azure CSP vs Microsoft Support

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-management, azure-management-portal

Azure customers (end-clients) can use a CSP(Cloud Solution Provider) to acquire services of Azure. But then Microsoft won't give support, all supports are handled by CSP. 
What difference does it make for the customer to use CSP compared to accessing Azure services(and support) directly from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

You can still obtain support from Microsoft but you must first go through the CSP.  If the CSP can't resolve, they can escalate.  Details on CSP support are outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/support/azure-csp-support-overview#escalate-problems-to-microsoft

Comment: Why can't you just included a Microsoft support package when you setup an Azure subscription though? Surely this doesn't require the CSP to be involved at all? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/support/plans/

Comment: You can get Microsoft supplied support on an Azure Sub if you are not doing CSP.  The whole point of CSP is that the partner can provide a deeper level of engagement.  That's why CSP has different pricing.  If you don't want to go through a partner, just buy Azure on the open market, don't go through a CSP.

Comment: thanks, on the subject of Azure & CSPs... say you have a CSP who fully manage your MS services (emails, users, Office365 etc.), but as a knowlegable customer you want to independently create and manage your own Azure Sub (+ resources in that Sub) housed within your CSP's tenancy. Is that possible? Normal practice?

Comment: @Theo, that's an interesting question that I honestly can't answer.  I don't think it's technically an issue but there may be contractual issues I am not aware of.  In my day job, I am a cloud solution architect so I let the AE's and Licensing folks field these types of questions.